# How to change property of button based on binded property in Xamarin and XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to use XAML and Xamarin to make a listview which contains labels with user information. Someone should be able to select multiple users from the list. If they want, they can use a "Select All" button at the top.

An unselected person should have a grey button with the text "Show Interest." A selected person should have a green button with the text "Remove Interest."

I've done this by creating a class with the information I need as well as the following:

```cs
public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
public Color ButtonColor { get { return IsSelected ? Color.LightGreen : Color.LightGray; } }
public string Status { get { return IsSelected ? "Remove\nInterest" : "Show\nInterest"; } }
```

And in xaml, I've bound the button's properties to the color and status:

```
<ListView x:Name="ItemsListView"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Results}"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                HasUnevenRows="True"
                IsPullToRefreshEnabled="False">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid>
                        <Button
                            Text="{Binding Status}"
                            BackgroundColor="{Binding ButtonColor}"
                            Clicked="ChangeInterest"
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.RowSpan="6"
                            Grid.Column="10"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
                            />
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

ChangedInterest just finds the appropriate item and switches "IsSelected." Since the properties are bound to the variables, and the variables are bound to IsSelected, shouldn't the buttons automatically be changed?

If, in the ChangedInterest function, I write
`(sender as Button).Text = Results[i].Status;`
and the appropriate line for the color, it changes.

The "Select All" button just scrolls through all the items in the list and sets IsSelected for each of them to be true. The desired result is for all the buttons to then change color and text based on the rules from the first block.

Is there a way to make the properties change automatically with the binding change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though you have used data binding , you can use **Command** instead of **ClickEvent** of button.

> in xaml

```
<Button
    Text="{Binding Status}"
    BackgroundColor="{Binding ButtonColor}"
    Command="{Binding Selected}"
    Grid.Row="0"
    Grid.RowSpan="6"
    Grid.Column="10"
    Grid.ColumnSpan="5"/>
```

> in your model

```
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    bool isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected {
        get { return isSelected; }

        set {                 
                isSelected = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();

                if(value)
                {
                    ButtonColor = Color.LightGreen;
                    Status = "Remove\nInterest";
                }
                else
                {
                    ButtonColor = Color.LightGray;
                    Status = "Show\nInterest";
                }               
        }
    }

    Color buttonColor;
    public Color ButtonColor {
        get { return buttonColor; }

        set {               
                buttonColor = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();                 
        }
    }

    string status;
    public string Status {
        get { return status; }

        set {                
                status = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();            
        }
    }


    public ICommand Selected { get; private set; }

    public Model()
    {
        Selected = new Command(() => { IsSelected = !IsSelected; });
    }

    protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been trying to get this pretty much all day today and yesterday, and this FINALLY worked! Thank you!